VS Code не удается найти путь
периодически возникает такая ошибка, в чем проблема?

cd : Не удается найти путь "D:\учеба 3 курс\3 курс 5 семестр\С", так как он не существует.
строка:1 знак:6
+  d:; cd 'd:\\учеба 3 курс\3 курс 5 семестр\С'; & 'c:\Users\ользовател ...
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\учеба 3 курс\3 курс 5 семестр\С:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
& : Имя "c:\Users\ользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. П 
роверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:50
+ ... местр\С'; & 'c:\Users\ользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pytho ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (c:\Users\ользов...n310\python.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

UPD: Проблема решена(надеюсь), необходимо переустановить Module PSReadLine. (https://danshin.ms/PSReadLine-problem/)
"Проблема не в VS Code, а в PowerShell, который используется им как консоль, и некоторые версии которого имеют проблемы с вводом заглавных букв."

Может из-за кирилицы? ользователь вместо пользователь //Рекомендуется проверить, корректен ли путь c:\Users\ользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe  вручную в Проводнике, чтобы убедиться, что Python установлен именно там.
